# C# WPF - Adding a child node to a selected node in treeview

Tags: wpf, treeview

In WPF treeview control, I need to add a child node to a parent node i select using mousedoubleclick event.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.treeview.selecteditem.aspx

I followed the step in the MSDN, but i get invalidCastException when i do this.

> TreeViewItem newChild =
>   (TreeViewItem)treeView1.SelectedItem;

How can i solve this?

Thanks

Comment: A better idea would be to bind your `TreeView` to an object graph, and have lazily loaded collection properties in that graph.

Answer (score 2):

`SelectedItem` returns the selected *data* item, not the visual representing it.

If you need to access the selected `TreeViewItem`, use the ItemContainerGenerator :

```
TreeViewItem item = treeView1.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(treeView1.SelectedItem) as TreeViewItem;
```

Not sure it works for nested items though... you might have to use the ItemContainerGenerator of the parent TreeViewItem, which wouldn't be very convenient

EDIT: just tested, indeed it only works for root nodes...

Anyway, the best way to add a node is to use bindings and `HierarchicalDataTemplate`s. You just need to add the object to the data source, and the corresponding TreeViewItem will be added automatically (provided the containing collection implements INotifyCollectionChanged...)

Answer (score 1):

What type of Items do you **Add()** to the Tree? The same type will be returned.
If it is mixed, use

```
TreeViewItem newChild = treeView1.SelectedItem as TreeViewItem;
if (newChild != null) { ... }
```