# WPF TreeView Selecteditem. Issue with adding child Items (VB,net)

Tags: wpf, vb.net, treeview

This may have a very simple solution but I am pretty new to this. I am trying add child items into a selected treeView item with the click of a button. Code works fine with nothing selected but seems `Treeview1.selectedItem` doesn't have an `.Add` method.

```
Imports System.Windows.Controls.TreeView
Class MainWindow
  Private Sub addNodeButton_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles addNodeButton.Click
    Dim n As String = "Model"
    If TreeView1.SelectedItem Is Nothing Then
        TreeView1.Items.Add(n)
    Else
        TreeView1.SelectedItem.add("test")
    End If
  End Sub
End Class
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Check [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1395493/c-sharp-wpf-adding-a-child-node-to-a-selected-node-in-treeview).

Comment: perfect. thanks. Seems I was adding N as string instead of TreeViewItem and thus couldnt add children.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I knew it would turn out to be simple. I was initially adding items as Strings insead of TreeViewItems and thus couldn't add children. Fixed code below:

```
Private Sub addNodeButton_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles addNodeButton.Click
    Dim n As New TreeViewItem
    n.Header = "Model"
    If TreeView1.SelectedItem Is Nothing Then
        TreeView1.Items.Add(n)
    Else
        Dim tempitem As New TreeViewItem
        tempitem = TreeView1.SelectedItem
        Dim newitem As New TreeViewItem
        newitem.Header = "test"
        tempitem.Items.Add(newitem)

    End If


End Sub
```